# Rails 3.1, has_many :through, habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```
class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :manifests
  has_many :parts, :through => :manifests
end

class Manifest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assembly
  belongs_to :part
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :manifests
  has_many :assemblies, :through => :manifests
end
```

Where `manifests` contains:

```
assembly_id
part_id
field1
field2
...
```

How can I update the others fields (`field1`, `field2`...) using habtm?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many you have to use a has_many-through instead of a habtm relationship (as you did it in your question). Then, you can simply use this code to set up the relationship between a part and an assembly:

```
#create assembly
ass1 = Assembly.new
ass1.save!

# create part
part_x = Part.new
part_x.save!

# create relationship between assembly and part using the join model Manifest
Manifest.new(assembly: ass1, part: part_x, field1: 1, field2: "test").save!
```